# Fact Table with Package

Tags: ssis, etl

I's like to ask about etl, and fact table.

Likely, my fact table's structure is like this :

```
Id   |    Name   |    QuestionAanswer    | QuestionBanswer   |  QuestionCanswer
```

I have dimension like this :

1. UserDimension
2. QuestionDimension
3. QuestionStaging

QuestionStaging data came from csv files, which the name is structurely randomed like A257_IDr, H1_ques1, H2_ques2, H3_ques3.
ex :

```
 A001 | 1 | 2 | 1  |
```

where `A001` -> UserID and  `1,2,1` -> User's answer to following question.

QuestionDimension's structure is like:

```
SK_Question | ID_Question | IDAnswer
```

ex. I have the following question like =

> How are yours company profit this year? Bad:Good:Best

then the data's structure in table is like :

```
Sk_Question | IDQuestion | IdAnswer | AnswerDetail
1                   Q1        1             Bad
2                   Q1        1             Good
3                   Q2        1             Best
```

My Expectation FactTable is likely to :

```
SK_USer |Id   |    Name   |    QuestionAanswer    | QuestionBanswer   |  QuestionCanswer
1        A001     Richard             1                    1                     2
```

OR

```
1        A001     Richard             Bad                   Bad                 Good
```

What data flow component or control flow should I used for these situation?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a flat file connection manager, dataflow control component, flat file data source task and, depending on your database, a data destination task (OLE DB probably).

Comment: yea, done already. But still, how I can update my fact table?

Comment: You can start by opening Business Intelligence Development Studio,  placing the aforementioned objects on the page, making an attempt at loading them in, then passing on any _specific_ question or error that you have. Have you created the tables yet?